# How to loop though entire dataframe in R and get the head function

Tags: r

Assume 3 `df`:

```
d1 <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
d2 <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
d3 <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
```

in R you can view the head of a dataframe with:

`head(d1)`

Now How can I write function/loop to see the `head` of all dataframes ?

Comment: You should put these data.frames in a list when you create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the dataframes in a list using `mget` and use `head` with `lapply` -

```
lapply(mget(paste0('d', 1:3)), head)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
dfs = ls(envir = .GlobalEnv, pattern = "^d")
lapply(dfs, function(x) head(get(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)))
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0   0
2  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0   1
3  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0   0
4  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0   0
5  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0   0
6  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   0

[[2]]
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   1
2  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0   1
3  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1   0
4  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0   0
5  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1
6  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0   0

[[3]]
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1   0
2  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   1
3  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0   0
4  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   1
5  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0   0
6  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   0
```

**NOTE**: This code assumes that all the variables whose names start with "d" is one of the `dataframes` that you want to include in the `head` function.